# How can I call operator methods by changing values in a panel?

Tags: python, properties, operator, panel

Currently I have a script that draws a line strip whose vertices depend on 2 boolean values, controlled from a panel. However, the line is only updated when the operator is invoked.

What I need is for the vertices to be able to change in real time toggling the boolean values from the panel. I know that I will need the operator's create_batch() method to be called whenever the boolean values are toggled, but I don't know how to make that happen.

(Please bear with me if this is obvious, I am still relatively new to scripting in Blender.)

```
import bpy
import gpu
from gpu_extras.batch import batch_for_shader
import bgl

wm = bpy.types.WindowManager
wm.enabled = bpy.props.BoolProperty( default = False )


class TestProperties( bpy.types.PropertyGroup ):
    test_1: bpy.props.BoolProperty( name = "1")
    test_2: bpy.props.BoolProperty( name = "2")


class TEST_OT_draw_operator( bpy.types.Operator ):
    bl_idname = "object.draw_op"
    bl_label = ""
    bl_options = { 'REGISTER' }

    def __init__( self ):
        self.draw_handle = None
        self.vertices = []

    def invoke( self, context, event ):
        if( context.window_manager.enabled is False ):
            self.create_batch( context )
            args = (self, context)
            self.register_handlers( args, context )
            context.window_manager.enabled = True
            return { "RUNNING_MODAL" }
        else:
            context.window_manager.enabled = False
            return { 'CANCELLED' }

    def register_handlers( self, args, context ):
        self.draw_handle = bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add( self.draw_callback, args, "WINDOW", "POST_VIEW" )
        context.window_manager.modal_handler_add( self )

    def unregister_handlers( self, context ):
        bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_remove( self.draw_handle, "WINDOW" )
        self.draw_handle = None

    def modal( self, context, event ):  
        if context.area:
            context.area.tag_redraw()
        if not context.window_manager.enabled:
            return self.finish( context )
        return { "PASS_THROUGH" }

    def finish( self, context ):
        self.unregister_handlers( context )
        return { "FINISHED" }

    def create_batch( self, context ):
        self.vertices = []

        if context.scene.test_properties.test_1:
            self.vertices.extend( [(0, 3, 3), (0, 4, 4), (0, 6, 2), (0, 3, 3)] )
        if context.scene.test_properties.test_2:
            self.vertices.extend( [(2, 3, 3), (0, 4, 4), (0, 6, 2), (2, 3, 3)] )

        self.shader = gpu.shader.from_builtin( '3D_UNIFORM_COLOR' )
        self.batch = batch_for_shader( self.shader, 'LINE_STRIP', { "pos": self.vertices } )

    def draw_callback( self, op, context):
        bgl.glLineWidth( 5 )
        self.shader.bind()
        self.shader.uniform_float( "color", (1, 0, 0, 1) )
        self.batch.draw( self.shader )


class TEST_PT_panel( bpy.types.Panel ):
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_label = "Test"
    bl_context = "objectmode"
    bl_category = "Test"

    def draw( self, context ):
        layout = self.layout
        if( context.window_manager.enabled ):
            layout.operator( "object.draw_op", text = "Stop" )
        else:
            layout.operator( "object.draw_op", text = "Start" )
        layout.prop( context.scene.test_properties, "test_1" )
        layout.prop( context.scene.test_properties, "test_2" )


classes = [TestProperties, TEST_OT_draw_operator, TEST_PT_panel]

def register():
    for cls in classes :
        bpy.utils.register_class( cls )
    bpy.types.Scene.test_properties = bpy.props.PointerProperty( type = TestProperties )

def unregister():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class( cls )
    del bpy.types.Scene.test_properties

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: Nice work. Only a small change for running update: move _self.create_batch( context )_ from `def invoke()` to `def modal()`

Comment: While that does not technically answer my question, it does give me a working solution for my problem. I'd prefer not to have the batch being called continuously, as that somewhat defeats the purpose of the batch, but that can be fixed easily enough with trigger conditions.